# Genrating more rows based on a colum, if criteria not matched SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have the following table, These table has information about the number of files and some other fields . This is a lookup table or reference table.

The oracle version i am using Oracle Database 18c Enterprise E

```
id             nm    expected_num_files     file_name_expr
1             CVS             3               cvs_d.*.zip
2             CVS             2               cvs_w.*.gz
3             Rite-aid        4               ra_d.*.gz
5             Walgreen        2               wal_d*.txt
```

I have a audit table which has the information received files. Both of those tables can be joined on id

```
audit_id    id  file_nm
123          1  cvs_d1.zip
124          1  cvs_d2.zip
125          2  cvs_w1.gz
126          1  cvs_d3.zip
```

The ideal case is where all the files received.

**Ideal Result**
select id , count(*) from auditlog group by id

```
   id              count_files 
    1                 3           
    2                 2           
    3                 4           
    5                 2
```

**CurrentResult of audit table**
But in current case i recieved only some files

```
   id              count_files
    1                 3           
    2                 1
```

In order to reach ideal case, i need to populate the dummy records in the final table from the lookup table with empty auditid

I need a final output table should like this.

If i perform the query `select id , count(*) from auditlog group by id`
on final table, i will get the ideal result that is highlighted above

```
audit_id  id  file_nm
    123      1  cvs_d1.zip
    124      1  cvs_d2.zip
    126      1  cvs_d3.zip
    -1       2  cvs_w.*.gz
    125      2  cvs_w1.gz
    -1       3  ra_d*.gz
    -1       3  ra_d.*.gz
    -1       3  ra_d.*.gz
    -1       3  ra_d.*.gz
    -1       5  wal_d*.txt
    -1       5  wal_d*.txt
```

We can generate the initail rows easily, but the rows with -1 are generated based on number of files not received form the column(number of files they didnt sent)

Explain final table: As we have 3 records for id 1 in the audit table so we populated them in the final table, But for id 2 we have one record in the audit table we populated that and for other record we populated -1.

Comment: file_name_expr doesn't match file_nm.

Comment: I read this 3 times, but i still don't understand what you want to do. Would you elaborate please?

Comment: @Sens, Can we have chat?

Comment: @Achyuth i'm only on the App right now, i don't know if it works there. But please

Comment: @Sens Can you check the question know

Comment: Your tags contain `oracle` and `apache-spark`. On which system are you trying to solve your problem? Oracle or Spark?

Comment: Can be done in oracle or in the spark.

Comment: @werner did you understood my question.

Comment: @Achyuth are you using Oracle PL/SQL or MySQL ? Both are different RDBMS; although owned by same organization (Oracle). And, if you are using MySQL, what is your MySQL server version ? Run `SELECT Version();` query to report the MySQL version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the data you have given, you can stay with the tables as the are and create a view that provides the data as needed:

```
WITH /* The following is the lookup data you provided: */
     lookup(id, nm, expected_num_files, file_name_expr) AS 
    (SELECT 1, 'CVS',     3,'cvs_d.*.zip' from dual union all
     SELECT 2, 'CVS',     2,'cvs_w.*.gz'  from dual union all
     SELECT 3, 'Rite-aid',4,'ra_d.*.gz'   from dual union all
     SELECT 5, 'Walgreen',2,'wal_d*.txt'  from dual)
   , /* This is the current auditlog as you described: */
     auditlog(audit_id, id, file_nm) AS
    (select 123, 1, 'cvs_d1.zip' from dual union all
     select 124, 1, 'cvs_d2.zip' from dual union all
     select 125, 2, 'cvs_w1.gz'  from dual union all
     select 126, 1, 'cvs_d3.zip' from dual)
   , rn AS (SELECT LEVEL rn FROM dual 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < (SELECT MAX(expected_num_files) FROM lookup))
/* This is the select you can put into a view: */
SELECT NVL(a.audit_id, -1) AS audit_id
     , NVL(a.id,l.id)      AS id
     , NVL(a.file_nm, l.file_name_expr) AS file_nm
  FROM lookup l
 /* Create a Row for every expected file: */
  JOIN rn r
    ON r.rn <= l.expected_num_files
 FULL JOIN (SELECT a.*
                 , row_number() over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY audit_id) AS rn 
              FROM auditlog a) a
   ON a.id = l.id
   AND a.rn = r.rn
 ORDER BY 2,1
```

Result:

```
AUDIT_ID | ID | FILE_NM
---------+----+-----------
   123   |  1 | cvs_d1.zip
   124   |  1 | cvs_d2.zip
   126   |  1 | cvs_d3.zip
   -1    |  2 | cvs_w.*.gz
   125   |  2 | cvs_w1.gz
   -1    |  3 | ra_d.*.gz
   -1    |  3 | ra_d.*.gz
   -1    |  3 | ra_d.*.gz
   -1    |  3 | ra_d.*.gz
   -1    |  5 | wal_d*.txt
   -1    |  5 | wal_d*.txt
```

An other way to write the query is the following:

```
WITH lookup(id, nm, expected_num_files, file_name_expr) AS 
    (SELECT 1, 'CVS',     3,'cvs_d.*.zip' from dual union all
     SELECT 2, 'CVS',     2,'cvs_w.*.gz'  from dual union all
     SELECT 3, 'Rite-aid',4,'ra_d.*.gz'   from dual union all
     SELECT 5, 'Walgreen',2,'wal_d*.txt'  from dual)
   , auditlog(audit_id, id, file_nm) AS
    (select 123, 1, 'cvs_d1.zip' from dual union all
     select 124, 1, 'cvs_d2.zip' from dual union all
     select 125, 2, 'cvs_w1.gz'  from dual union all
     select 126, 1, 'cvs_d3.zip' from dual) 
   , rn AS (SELECT LEVEL rn FROM dual 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < (SELECT MAX(expected_num_files) FROM lookup))
SELECT * FROM auditlog
UNION ALL 
SELECT -1, l.id, l.file_name_expr
  FROM lookup l
  JOIN rn r
    ON r.rn <= l.expected_num_files - NVL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auditlog WHERE id = l.id),0)
 ORDER BY 2,1
```

Comment: Is there any other option than cross join. There is performance impact because i have millions of records

Comment: I have changed the query a bit using a join instead of the cross join. Not sure if it is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

> > Is there any other option than cross join. There is performance impact because i have millions of records

That's always hard to judge.  A `CROSS APPLY` *may* be faster.  At the least, it saves the work of generating a lot of rows that end up getting discarded.  It might be worth trying.

```
SELECT coalesce(al.audit_id,-1) audit_id, 
       s.id, 
       coalesce(al.file_nm, s.file_name_expr) file_nm
FROM audit_summary s 
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT rownum rn FROM dual CONNECT BY rownum <= s.expected_num_files ) ef
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT row_number() over ( partition by al.id ORDER BY al.audit_id ) rn, 
                           al.file_nm, 
                           al.audit_id, 
                           al.id 
                    FROM   audit_log al 
                    WHERE  al.id = s.id) al ON al.rn = ef.rn
ORDER BY 2,3,1;
```

Here is a full example with data:

```
WITH audit_summary (id, nm, expected_num_files, file_name_expr ) AS
( SELECT 1, 'CVS', 3, 'cvs_d.*.zip' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'CVS', 2, 'cvs_w.*.gz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Rite-aid', 4, 'ra_d.*.gz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Walgreen', 2, 'wal_d*.txt' FROM DUAL),
audit_log (audit_id, id, file_nm) AS 
( SELECT 123, 1, 'cvs_d1.zip' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 124, 1, 'cvs_d2.zip' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 125, 2, 'cvs_w1.gz' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 126, 1, 'cvs_d3.zip' FROM DUAL )
SELECT coalesce(al.audit_id,-1) audit_id, 
       s.id, 
       coalesce(al.file_nm, s.file_name_expr) file_nm
FROM audit_summary s 
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT rownum rn FROM dual CONNECT BY rownum <= s.expected_num_files ) ef
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT row_number() over ( partition by al.id ORDER BY al.audit_id ) rn, 
                           al.file_nm, 
                           al.audit_id, 
                           al.id 
                    FROM   audit_log al 
                    WHERE  al.id = s.id) al ON al.rn = ef.rn
ORDER BY 2,3,1;
```

> ```
> +----------+----+------------+
> | AUDIT_ID | ID |  FILE_NM   |
> +----------+----+------------+
> |      123 |  1 | cvs_d1.zip |
> |      124 |  1 | cvs_d2.zip |
> |      126 |  1 | cvs_d3.zip |
> |       -1 |  2 | cvs_w.*.gz |
> |      125 |  2 | cvs_w1.gz  |
> |       -1 |  3 | ra_d.*.gz  |
> |       -1 |  3 | ra_d.*.gz  |
> |       -1 |  3 | ra_d.*.gz  |
> |       -1 |  3 | ra_d.*.gz  |
> |       -1 |  4 | wal_d*.txt |
> |       -1 |  4 | wal_d*.txt |
> +----------+----+------------+
> ```

I was split on whether the `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` was helpful or not.  It's the same as a simple `LEFT JOIN` with the `al.id = s.id` condition moved from the lateral view to the join condition.  I have a vague idea of the `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` making it so you can run the query piecemeal (by `audit_summary.id`) if there are specific files you suspect are missing.